# How to get list of validators which delegator delegated in Near protocol

Tags: validation, delegates, delegation, nearprotocol

I want to get list of validators which delegator delegated in Near protocol.

I can get delegations list for validator.

How can I get validators list from delegator in Near?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to check every staking pool individually calling a view function on every one of them with the given account id (either [`get_account_staked_balance` or `get_account_unstaked_balance`](https://github.com/near/core-contracts/blob/dad58eb5f968c25913e746028ad63980506f5890/staking-pool/src/lib.rs#L320-L336)). It is not efficient and floods RPC servers, so if it is not a one-off operation, you should consider implementing a light-weight indexer that would keep track of who delegated where.